# Store class definition in dictionary, instance later

Tags: c#, dictionary, lazy-loading

What I want to do is something like the following (All object class have a common interface):

```
MyDict.Add("A", MyAObjectClass); // Not an instance
MyDict.Add("B", MyBObjectClass);
MyDict.Add("C", MyCOjbectClass);
String typeIwant = "B"; // Could be passed to a function or something
MyCommonInterface myobject = MyDict[typeIwant]();
```

How could I program something like this?

The purpose of this is to not have to create instances of every single type I will store in my dictionary (could be quite a bit of them) and instead only instance the one I'm actually going to use.

Answer (score 6):

You can store type information with a Type object:

```
var dict = new Dictionary<String, Type>();

dict.Add("A", typeof(TextBox));
dict.Add("B", typeof(Button));
```

and create objects from it like this:

```
object a = Activator.CreateInstance(dict["A"]);
```

This will only work with types with a parameterless constructor.  For instance, `new TextBox()`.  If your types have constructors that take the same arguments, you can add the arguments after `dict["A"]` or pass an array.

Answer (score 3):

I strongly recommend using a dependency injection library like `Unity` or `Windsor Castle`, but if you absolutely must, then you should do something like this:

```
Dictionary<string, System.Type> MyDict = new Dictionary<string, System.Type>();
MyDict.Add("A", typeof(MyAObjectClass));
MyDict.Add("B", typeof(MyBObjectClass));
MyDict.Add("C", typeof(MyCObjectClass));

string typeIwant = "B";
var myobject = Activator.CreateInstance(MyDict[typeIwant]);
```

Comment: If this really satisfies the requirement, why add the *huge* complexity (compared to this solution) of a separate framework?

Comment: @SimonC: what makes you think that adding a framework like `Unity` adds "huge" complexity? The code actually will reduce, and more so, as the list of instantiable classes grows.

Comment: You've still got to configure the framework with the mapping of 'name' to type somehow which is going to grow in exactly the same way as the dictionary, but then you have to learn how the framework is configured, what the API is, what bugs may exist, etc, and so does everyone else who maintains your code .

Comment: I'm not against using an IoC style framework if the requirements make sense, but given the simple requirements in the question, an additional framework would be overkill.

Comment: @SimonC: if you're using `Activator` extensively enough that you want to dictionary the types of classes and instantiate them later on, there's probably a good chance that you should be using a dependency injection framework. That's the reason why they came up with Unity and Castle.