# how to make a new object of an type variable in a Dictionary if the type has constructor arguments c#

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance, dictionary

```
class baseClass
{         
    public baseClass(int x,int y) {}
}
class class1 : baseClass
{    
    public class1(int x,int y) : base (x,y) {}
}
public void Main()
{

    Dictionery<int,Type> classes = new Dictionery<int,Type>();
    classes.add(1,typeof(Class1));

    baseClass x = new classes[1] (10 , 12); // doesent work

    //tried
    baseClass x = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(classes[2](10, 12))
    //tried
    baseClass x = Activator.CreateInstanceFrom(classes[2], 10, 12)
}
```

i found this post : [Store class definition in dictionary, instance later](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13188784/store-class-definition-in-dictionary-instance-later)

and an anwser saying :  If your types have constructors that take the same arguments, you can add the arguments after dict["A"]

but then, how is the syntax to do that ?

I would just leave a comment on the post but i don't gott the reputation to do so... :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use such [this overload of `CreateInstance`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wcxyzt4d(v=vs.110).aspx) to create the object that you need:

```
baseClass x = (baseClass)Activator.CreateInstance(classes[1], 10, 12);
```

In this case there are 3 parameters that are passed to the `CreateInstance` method: class type and array of parameters.

You also need to cast it to `baseClass`, because `CreateInstance` method returns `object`.

Answer (score 0):

I went through the post and I am not sure either. I am just wondering what about creating a custom class and pass parameters while creating Dictionary Instance. I am just assuming you know the parameter every class needs while creating dictionary's instance. Please go through the code below:

```
class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var dictionary = new Dictionary<string, TypeCreator>();
            dictionary.Add("A", new TypeCreator(typeof(CustomA),"parameter1"));
            dictionary.Add("B", new TypeCreator(typeof(CustomB), "parameter1", "parameter2"));

            var instance = dictionary["A"].GetInstance();
        }        
    }

    public class TypeCreator
    {
        public TypeCreator(Type type, params object[] args)
        {
            CustomType = type;
            Params = args;
        }
        public Type CustomType { get; set; }
        public object[] Params { get; set; }

        public Object GetInstance()
        {
            return Activator.CreateInstance(CustomType, Params);
        }
    }

    public class CustomA
    {
        public CustomA(string param1)
        {

        }
    }

    public class CustomB
    {
        public CustomB(string param1, string param2)
        {

        }
    }
```